# r Keras Can't load cifar10

Tags: r, ssl, keras, anaconda

I'm working in RStudio and I finally got Keras working with my GPU. I tried to load the cifar10 dataset with

```
cifar <- dataset_cifar10()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz: None -- [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)
```

I've seen solutions for the Python equivalent in changing SSL settings, but how would I do that in R?

Comment: This isn't a `TensorFlow` question. Are you able to use with `http` http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz ?

Comment: I am able to access the website with https and HTTP. Keras provides functions to download datasets, e.g.  `dataset_reuters() `, which works fine, but for some reason `dataset_cifar10() ` keeps throwing this issue. I'm not sure if it's an issue with config or on their end.